# Results of zipped list with string

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to write a piece of code that, when printed, returns "The square of *user input* is X."

What I've got is as follows:

```
nums = range(0, 11)
squares = [x**2 for x in nums]
list = (zip(nums, squares))
user = raw_input("Please select a number between 1 and 10. ")

print ( ????????? for (x,y) in zip(nums, squares))
```

I'm completely stuck. The last line is a bit of a guess, and I'm not sure how to pull it all together.

What should I do here?

Comment: why do you need zip as opposed to `f"The square of {user} is {squares[user-1]}"` (with error handling)

Comment: try `x = int(input("Please select a number between 1 and 10. "))
print(f'The square of  user input {x} is {x**2}')` - it should work

Comment: You should not assign the value of `zip` to a special keyword `list`

Answer (score 0):

The mapping between numbers and squares might be more nicely accomplished with a dictionary:

```
nums = range(0, 11)
squares = {x:x**2 for x in nums}
user = int(input("Please select a number between 1 and 10. "))
square = squares[user]
print('The square of %d is %d' % (user, square))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply print the corresponding sqr of the number like this:

```
print(f"Square of {user} is {squares[user-1]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

```
nums = range(0, 11)
squares = [x**2 for x in nums]
liste = (zip(nums, squares))
user = input("Please select a number between 1 and 10. ")

print ( 'The square of '+ user+' is '+str(squares[int(user)]))
```

You shouldn't write list as the name of a variable as it is a function in Python.